# How to get all objects referenced as ForeignKey from given field in a module in django

Tags: python, django

I have two classes: Author and Book. I want class Authors to have an attribute that contains all books written by the said author, as referenced to as foreign key in the class Books. The method I did does not appear to be working, which I assume is because when the database is being created in migrations, no Books objects exist yet. Or so I believe, I'm pretty new at django.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    AuthorName = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    books = Book.objects.get(pk=object_instance.pk)

class Book(models.Model):
    BookName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Author = models.ForeignKey('Author')
```

The error message I get is:

```
NameError: name 'Book' is not defined
```

Which I get, is because I'm referencing to another class without actually having and instance of that class. I just can't figure out a proper way to do this.

EDIT: I reformatted it to be like this:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    AuthorName = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    books = author.book_set.all()

class Book(models.Model):
    BookName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Author = models.ForeignKey('Author')
```

which yields error:

```
NameError: name 'author' is not defined
```

Maybe I should just query for the datapoints I need later on in views as opposed to creating own field for them in models though..

EDIT 2: solution from answers:

So my mistake all along was to try to add the "books" field in the author table. I guess there's no way to do this then. I can get that method to work in views so I guess this is sort of solved, although not in the way I was originally planning to do it.

doing

```
class Author(models.Model):
    AuthorName = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    BookName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Author = models.ForeignKey('Author')
```

and then later doing this in views:

```
author = Author.objects.get(pk=1)
books = author.book_get.all()
```

yields the wanted result (which I sort of knew beforehand, but I was trying to implement a books field in the models, which, if i correctly understood, is not possible at least not with this method).

another solution:

```
class Author(models.Model):
    AuthorName = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    BookName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name = "books")
```

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)? Django provides this method for you automatically.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about using that in models. If this was traditional python I believe I could query for them with `author = self.objects.get(pk=self.pk)` and then add the related objects with `books = author.book_set.all()` but in django this yields error of "self" not being defined.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You don't need to create a separate field in `Authors` model

```
class Author(models.Model):
    AuthorName = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    BookName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    Author = models.ForeignKey('Author')
```

You can get all books of a particular author like:

```
author = Author.objects.get(id=1)
books = author.book_set.all()
```

Learn more about backward relationships [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Answer (score 17):

Just add `related_name` to ForeignKey and you will be able to get all books made by an author.

For example:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    ...
    author = models.ForeignKey('Author', related_name='books')
    ...
```

and later...

```
author = Author.objects.get(pk=1)
books = author.books.all()
```

Comment: It should be `all()`

Answer (score 4):

You did something weird in line:

```
books = Book.objects.get(pk=object_instance.pk)
```

Just delete it. You will be able to use `author.book_set`. You can also use `related_name` parameter of `ForeignKey`.

See the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: Thanks, I still get this error message when i use that method though:

    NameError: name 'author' is not defined. As a clarifiacation, I'm still trying to do this in models as opposed to doing it in views, where I could also do this, I guess.

Comment: In models just delete the line. In views you can access author's books with `author.book_set`. Don't forget to define `author`!

Comment: Yeah so my mistake all along was to try to add the "books" field in the author table. I guess there's no way to do this then. I can get that method to work in views so it's fine.

Comment: Use it like in Anush's answer. By the way don't call model properties with `CamelCase` but `with_underscores`.

Comment: so implementing books field in the author model is not possible, but rather the books should later be queried in views?

Comment: The `book_set` field is created automaticly and I don't know another method. Why does it make problem to you? You can rename this field with `related_name`.