# How do I pass a specific CustomUser to the class-based CreateView in Django?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-custom-user

After finishing a tutorial, I decided to convert the function-based views in the app to class-based views as a way to learn both better. But I got stumped with passing the fields of a CustomUser to the CreateView:

```
#model:
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    user_type_data=((1,"HOD"),(2,"Staff"),(3,"Student"))
    user_type=models.CharField(default=1, choices=user_type_data, max_length=10)

class Staff(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin=models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    email=models.EmailField()
    address=models.TextField(blank=True)
    objects=models.Manager()

#view:
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class SubjectCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Subject
    fields = ['id', ... ]
```

What I want to put in the `fields=` are: `staff.first_name`, `staff.last_name`, but none of the combinations I tried worked. This is my first encounter with CustomUser, so my searches weren't fruitful. Appreciate some pointers.

Comment: You have to create a form with those fields and attach that form to the CreateView.

Comment: Is that the only way to do it? There is a `forms.py` in the app, I'll try to set up a staff create form. But I'd really like to know how to tap into the CustomUser in situations like this. As foreign key items, the ids, first_names and last_names of the `staff` seem to have no problem showing up in related list (`course_list`), but why can't the same info show up on the pages for `staff`?

Comment: there might be other ways, you have to make the question clear and add more details, you haven't specified what is the subject to staff relation?

Answer (score 0):

What I post below doesn't solve my problem with `CreateView`, but if you are similarly stuck, [this post offers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22846048/5965865) one of the tips on how to display all the fields in ModelForms (`fields = '__all__'`). And [this thread](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/34184291/5965865) offers tips on how to get objects referenced as ForeignKey.

If someone can help explain how to set up a CreateView for a CustomUser with fields that aren't listed in `models.py`-but maybe coming out of `AbstractUser` or `BaseUser`, I'll accept it as the answer.